# Displaying Data in a DataGrid (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Please consider the following DataModel

Since i'm new in here i can't post images so i'll try another method...

**Job entity**
-jobId
-jobNo
-jobStatus (Foreign Key from Status entity)
-jobDate

**Status entity**
-statusId
-statusCaption

**Relationship**
Job Entity * ----------- 0..1 Status Entity

I have a WCF Service that exposes the model to be accessed by my JobsViewModel

```
namespace PM.DataService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class PMService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public ObservableCollection<Job> GetAllJobs()
        {
            using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
            {
                var result = context.Jobs.ToList();
                result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
                return new ObservableCollection<Job>(result);
            }
        }

        [OperationContract]
        public ObservableCollection<Status> GetStatuses()
        {
            using (var context = new logisticDBEntities())
            {
                var result = context.Statuses.ToList();
                result.ForEach(e => context.Detach(e));
                return new ObservableCollection<Status>(result);
            }
        }        
    }
}

namespace PM.UI.ViewModel
{
    public class JobsViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private PMServiceClient serviceClient = new PMServiceClient();

    public JobsViewModel()
    {
        this.RefreshStatuses();
        this.RefreshAllJobs();
    }

    private void RefreshAllJobs()
    {
        this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.allJobs = e.Result;
        };
        this.serviceClient.GetAllJobsAsync();
    }

    private void RefreshStatuses()
    {
        this.serviceClient.GetStatusesCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Statuses = e.Result;
        };
        this.serviceClient.GetStatusesAsync();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Job> allJobs;
    public ObservableCollection<Job> AllJobs
    {
        get{
            return this.allJobs;
        }
        set
        {
            this.allJobs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllJobs");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Status> statuses;
    public ObservableCollection<Status> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statuses;
        }

            set
            {
                this.statuses = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Statuses");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

I included the JobsViewModel in the xaml of my MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="PM.FullClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PM.UI"
    xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:PM.UI.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="475" Width="575">
 <Window.DataContext>
    <vms:JobsViewModel/>
 </Window.DataContext>
....
```

Now i can easily populate a DataGrid on my MainWindow by binding to show all the Statuses

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Statuses}" Margin="7,8,9,8" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

and it works, but i can't show the output cos i can't post images in here

But when I try to do the same thing with Jobs... Nothing is happening. **The datagrid is EMPTY**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllJobs}" Margin="6">
</DataGrid>
```

I've gone through many menthods searched tons of fourms and websites and finally i'm here.

Could it be cos of the Status > Job relationship between Jobs and Statuses? If so how can i fix this and if Not what i'm a doing wrong?

Comment: Check the data in alljobs property is it getting populated...BTW INotifyPropertychanged is not needed in you case.

Comment: I think you should mention the difference between `Job` and `Status` classes.

Comment: @paritosh: The ViewModel uses an asynchronous service to fetch data, so INotifyPropertyChanged is in fact needed when the data finally arrives.

Comment: but the is the observable collection which do this things automatically ,I dont see any reason to raise the Propertychanged event.

Comment: If I'm using Observable Collection, I don't need INotyfyPropertyChanged? What is the primary difference between them? also wanna let you guys know that I'm going to be enhancing this to use Icommand also in the future. Thanx for the feedback guys...

Comment: @paritosh (&Hassan): On startup, allJobs/AllJobs is <null> - there is no collection there. INotifyPropertyChanged is needed to notify the View when the RefreshAllJobs() callback actually puts a collection into AllJobs. Like you say, further changes (adding/removing) **within** that collection is handled by ObservableCollection, but we need INotifyPropertyChanged to tell the View that there is a new collection to be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the RefreshAllJobs() callback, you set the **allJobs** field (lower-case 'a'), and not the **AllJobs** property (upper-case 'A'), and then OnPropertyChanged() never gets called from the *property* setter.